# How to pair items in two different lists using range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to make a dictionary using the two lists, Loop through a sorted version of that dictionary. Print out the name, followed by a space, followed by a colon, followed by a space, then finally the alias.
Eg. Stirling : Duchess
put what I did literally just prints out the name dict. ??

```
name = ["Stirling","Lana","Cyril","Pam","Ray","Cheryl"]
alias =["Duchess","Truckasaurus","Chet","Cookie Monster","Gilles de Rais","Cherlene"]

randomV = {}

for i in range(0,len(name)):
    item = [name, alias]


for word in name and alias:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Check out the built in zip function.  It allows you to iterate through multiple lists simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
names = ["Stirling","Lana","Cyril","Pam","Ray","Cheryl"]
aliases =["Duchess","Truckasaurus","Chet","Cookie Monster","Gilles de Rais","Cherlene"]

for name, alias in zip(names, aliases):
    print "{} : {}".format(name, alias)
```

To create a single dict, `d = dict(zip(names, aliases))`.

Your attempt has several problems: `item` is the same exact value each time through your first loop, since you never actually use the value of `i`, and `name and alias` simply evaluates to the first non-empty list (i.e., `name`). You wanted perhaps

```
items = []
for i in range(len(name)):
    item[i] = (name[i], alias[i])

for word in items:
    print(word[0], ":", word[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get `dict` from two lists, create a zipped version of both list and type-cast it to `dict`. You will get the dictionary object with the mapping.

```
# If order of insertion does not matter
dict(zip(names, aliases))

# OrderedDict if order matters
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict(zip(name, alias))
```

Sample run:

```
>>> name = ["Stirling","Lana","Cyril","Pam","Ray","Cheryl"]
>>> alias =["Duchess","Truckasaurus","Chet","Cookie Monster","Gilles de Rais","Cherlene"]
>>> dict(zip(name, alias))
{'Cheryl': 'Cherlene', 'Cyril': 'Chet', 'Lana': 'Truckasaurus', 'Stirling': 'Duchess', 'Pam': 'Cookie Monster', 'Ray': 'Gilles de Rais'}
```

If you just want to print the content, no need to type cast the dict. Simply iterate over the zipped list:

```
for name, alias in zip(names, aliases):
    print "{} : {}".format(name, alias)
```

---

Since you have explicitly mentioned to use `range()`. It could be done via:

```
list_len = len(names)  # OR, len(aliases), assuming both will have same length

my_dict = {}
for i in range(list_len):
    my_dict[names[i]] = aliases[i]  # for creating dict
    print "{} : {}".format(names[i], aliases[i])  # for printing content
```

Answer (score 0):

> a sorted version of that dictionary.

Dictionaries by their nature in python are unsorted but that does not really matter because all you need is a key to get the value associated with it.

```
name = ["Stirling","Lana","Cyril","Pam","Ray","Cheryl"]
alias =["Duchess","Truckasaurus","Chet","Cookie Monster","Gilles de Rais","Cherlene"]

dict = {}

for i in range(len(name)):
    dict[name[i]] = alias[i]
```

and if you wanted to print the items in the dictionary you can use:

```
for key in dict:
print(key + " : " + dict[key])
```